# Simple If/Else problem with 1/8 test case failed

Tags: java, if-statement

Simple If-Else problem, please advise:

My objective is as follows:

"Given an integer, n , perform the following conditional actions:

If n is odd, print "Weird"

If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print "Not Weird"

If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print "Weird"

If n is even and greater than 20 , print "Not Weird"

Upon completion, a website that I use automatically checks for all 8 test cases that are involved in this problem in which there is 1 that I got incorrect and all the others correct.

The test case is as follows:

Input(stdin) = 29

Output(stdout) = Not Weird

Expected Output = Weird

This is what I have done so far:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {



    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
        
        if(N % 2 == 0 & N >= 2 & N <= 5){
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        } else if (N >= 6 & N <= 20){
            System.out.println("Weird");
        } else if (N > 20){
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I have missed out??

Comment: Be careful not confusing the  & (binary AND) operator and the && (logical AND) operator. your code looks fine, only change the & for && on the if statements and you should be ok

Comment: Your else-block is reachable only for N=1,3,5. Also, you should try to write if-else block in exact sequence of the conditions mentioned in the questions to avoid any issue/missing test-case.

Comment: Your conditionals do not separate the checks on odd and even numbers. All odd numbers should be called wierd, so it would be a good first check to get them out of the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code uses a chain of `if` / `else if` blocks, whicih means that only one of the 4 'indented' `System.out` lines can ever run.

So, just.. do what programmers do. Debug this code. If you must, take out a pen, and run this code 'in your head'.

Let's say N is 21. It's odd, so, that is 'Weird', and it should just end there.

So let's go through it:

Is `N` **all** of these things:

- Even (`N % 2 == 0`)
- 2 or more
- 5 or less

Clearly no, so moving on to the second condition.

Is N 6 or more *and* 20 or less? No, moving on to the third.

Is N more than 20?  yes it is, so `Not Weird` is printed and that's that.

There you go, wrong answer.

I could just write you the right answer, but presumably your aim is to learn things. You may want to think about why you decided to flip the problem description around when you wrote your code. Why does the problem description **start** with 'if it is odd, then the answer is Weird, no exceptions', but your code starts with a completely different case (even and between 2 and 5)?

Closing notes:

- Your 'skip' call to scanner is bizarre and not needed. What you're looking for is, immediately after making a scanner, to run `scanner.useDelimiter("\\R")`, which covers that giant ball in a much simpler letter, and actually does what you want.
- `&` vs `&&` as applied when both 'sides' are booleans: It's basically the same thing; the only change is that with `&&`, the code 'shortcuts' - if the answer is already clear, going from left to right, then further expressions aren't evaluated. This doesn't mean anything unless evaluating an expression has side-effects. For example, If you have: `public boolean foo() { System.out.println("EVAL");}`, then `false & foo()` will print `EVAL`, whereas `false && foo()` won't; that `false` means the 'and' will be false regardless of what `foo()` does. In other words, `&&` is 'correct' in the sense that this is how java programmers write and it is 'more efficient', but the actual effect is moot in your specific code, so that doesn't break or make your algorithm :)

Answer (score 0):

In the third case you forgot to check if the number is even.
So, 29 > 20 and it goes to the third case.Second the right symbol for and is"&&" not "&".
I think that i corrected them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int N = 29;


    if(N % 2 == 0 && N >= 2 && N <= 5){
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
    } else if (N >= 6 && N <= 20){
        System.out.println("Weird");
    } else if (N > 20  && N % 2 == 0){
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep 1 sec as I make the changes and see everything is good to go

Answer (score 0):

my answer as below, for your reference:)

if **name** == '**main**':
n = int(input().strip())
n in range(101)

```
if n%2==1:
    print("Weird")
elif n in range (2,6) and n%2==0:
    print("Not Weird")
elif n in range(6,21) and n%2==0:
    print("Weird")
elif n>20 and n%2==0:
    print("Not Weird")
else:
    print("Not Weird")
```